# Orbit wordpress plugin bullets to show as thumbnail navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation, orbit

I am using orbit slider (with wp foundation) and trying to show bullet navigation. I really want to show the bullets as thumbnails, but right now they won't show in any way. I have bullets selected in the Orbit prefs in wordpress dashboard and I am using the following code in my js file and css. Appreciate some help.

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('#featured').orbit({
        bullets: true,
        bulletThumbs: true,
        bulletThumbLocation: '../thumbs/'
    }); 
});


.orbit-bullets li.has-thumb {
    width: 99px;
    height: 88px; 
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each image that the slider is displaying should have the attribute "data-thumb", like this:

```
<img src="IMAGE_NAME.jpg" data-thumb="THUMBNAIL_NAME.jpg" />
```

Hope this helped.